# cannot get rid of duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I have following table in my database:
[image]

All I need is to load Country list for User with ID=5:

- USA
- Canada
- Germany

Then, when I will click for example on USA, it will load the cities for that country:

- Washington DC
- Miami

I can display country field for every row where User ID=5 but I will have the following result which is not acceptable.

- USA
- Canada
- USA
- Germany
- Canada
- Germany

Are there any tricks which can help me not to duplicate country values?

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM <table> WHERE UserID = 5;` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `DISTINCT` to remove duplicate values from your resultset:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM <table> WHERE UserID = 5;
```

Reference: [How to Use MySQL DISTINCT to Eliminate Duplicate Rows](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Krister says, part 1 is

SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY FROM TABLE WHERE USERID =5

Then to get cities for that user in USA:

SELECT  CITY FROM TABLE WHERE USERID =5 AND COUNTRY = 'USA'